# Override CreateCredentials from SocialLoginProvider in azure app services

Tags: azure-api-apps, azure-mobile-services

I want to store user information to a db after a user successfully logged in via a social provider (google, facebook, etc.) without calling an extra api on the client side.

In azure mobile services this is done by creating a class that inherity from e.g. GoogleLoginProvider and then by overwriting the CreateCredentials method.

See this post: [Save information immediately after Google login in Azure Mobile Services (.NET Back-end)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550473/save-information-immediately-after-google-login-in-azure-mobile-services-net-b)

But how can I archive the same behaviour in Azure App Services?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what user information you're looking for, and why an API call won't work for you? There are some options available, but additional context would be helpful.

Comment: Hi,
I simply want to create a record in a usertable after a new user registers via social login.
Basically I have exaclty the same problem as stated in link above and the solution would be perfect (but it is for azure mobile services).

Furthermore I want to add custom claims to the claimsidentity - for instalce my local userId or a role (to enable role based authorization):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with App Service authentication. The authentication happens outside of your application and there aren't currently any direct hooks into the authentication pipeline. This also means you will not be able to inject custom claims into the ClaimsIdentity.

We are aware of some of these scenarios and want to try and address them, but don't have any timelines to share at this point. I believe the separate API call into the backend will be required in order for you to implement your registration. As far as implementing role-based access control, you will likely need to store the additional user metadata elsewhere.